# Receive Unknown?

Tags: nft, phantom, signing

When customers go to my NFT project to claim/buy an NFT, wallet shows "Receive Unknown" (image from phantom extension attached). What should I do to have the name of the NFT pop up on Phantom and other wallets? I have already set the name of the NFT and collection info on metadata.

[image: phantom]

Comment: If im not mistaken (please someone correct me if i am) it will only show after the collection is verified.